# Template for iterator type

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I want to create a template method for adding and counting of elements in a map (stl) independently from element type. The question is: can I use a template for the iterator type as shown below?

```
template < typename Type, typename Iter >
void TextStat::addElement(Type element, map<Type, int> map, Iter &it) {

    it = map.find(element);
    if ( it == map.end() ) {
        map.insert(pair<Type, int>(element, 1));
    } else {
        it->second += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: the best option would be to compile and run and see what happens

Comment: note that you are working with a copy of the map and a copy of the element..

Comment: The way to do this would be simply `theMap[theKey]++;`

Comment: Thanks! It was my mistake. Now with: "void TextStat::addElement(Type element, map<Type, int> &map, Iter &it)" I achieved needed result

Comment: Note that you may avoid to use `map` variable name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write your method like this:

```
template <typename Type>
void TextStat::addElement(const Type& element, std::map<Type, int>& m) {
    std::map<Type, int>::iterator it = m.find(element);

    if (it == m.end()) {
        m.insert(std::pair<Type, int>(element, 1));
    } else {
        it->second += 1;
    }
}
```

or even simpler, as default value initialization of `int` is `0`:

```
template <typename Type>
void TextStat::addElement(const Type& element, std::map<Type, int>& m) {
    m[element]++;
}
```